# Socket.error with foreman start: Tesing deploying a simple flask app to Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask

#### The Problem

`socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use`

#### What I'm doing

I'm testing a simple flask app with `foreman start` in my local environment. The app contains a few functions but its erroring here:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The full trace is shown below. I'm not sure what could wrong, or how the socket could already be in use on my local machine. When I run the app with `python runapp.py` from the terminal everything works fine.

#### What I've tired.

[Heroku, flask, and python sockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124630/heroku-flask-and-python-sockets)

[Deploying Flask app to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714205/deploying-flask-app-to-heroku)

following that last question  I tired to change the port it runs on by using

```
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    import os 
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000)) 
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

But it didnt help. Any suggestions would be appreciated! I'm new to Heroku so please let me know if there is anymore information I can provided to make solving this easier. Thanks!

Stack trace of error:

```
        22:13:45 web.1  | started with pid 11121
        22:13:45 web.1  |  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
        22:13:45 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
        22:13:45 web.1  |   File "Hunch/Hunch/hunchapp.py", line 49, in <module>
        22:13:45 web.1  |     app.run()
        22:13:45 web.1  |   File "/home/agconti/my_dev/github/Hunch/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 772, in run
        22:13:45 web.1  |     run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
        22:13:45 web.1  |   File "/home/agconti/my_dev/github/Hunch/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 706, in run_simple
        22:13:45 web.1  |     test_socket.bind((hostname, port))
        22:13:45 web.1  |   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
        22:13:45 web.1  |     return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
        22:13:45 web.1  | socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
        22:13:45 web.1  | exited with code 1
        22:13:45 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

Comment: "Address already in use" means that the port you want your app to use (5000) is already used. Try the command from one of your linked posts: ``heroku config:add PORT=33507``

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer Thanks! I had tried that before but I revisited it after your suggestion and found a the solution. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Soultion:

from terminal:

```
heroku config:add PORT=33507
```

Then change your app to:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        import os  
        port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 33507)) 
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

It seems that heroku reserves flask's default port for its own purposes. A detailed discussion can be found here: [Deploying Flask app to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714205/deploying-flask-app-to-heroku).

Answer (score 1):

When you terminate the flask application, use "Control + C."  If you use "Control + Z" it will leave the remaining report activate for some reason... I don't know why, but this seems to be the case for me in Debian (wheezy).