# Heroku incoming ports, and JMS

Tags: heroku, jms

We're evaluating Heroku for our java webapp. We read there's a limitation on incoming socket communication:
[Heroku, flask, and python sockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124630/heroku-flask-and-python-sockets)

Does that mean my webapp cannot register for JMS Topics (publish/subscribe pattern)? AFAIK JMS listeners work by listenning on a port (separate from the HTTP port).

And if there is such a limitation, how come I see Heroku addons such as CloudAMQP ... how can they listen to messages? Do they poll instead?
Thanks very much.

Comment: you connect to any external server from heroku, and then you can do whatever on that connection, as subscribe, consume etc. That's how CloudAMQP works, where you connect to an external RabbitMQ server, so the client app doesn't listen to any external ports.