# Is there a way to use plain socket apps on heroku?

Tags: java, ruby, sockets, http, heroku

I am trying to make a little game in java and it needs to ask a server to verify it's data.

I'd like to use heroku because I want to write the server in ruby with sinatra but I don't really know a good way to get websockets working with java.

My last bet is just to use normal sockets within ruby but because of the way heroku does it's port routing normal socket apps don't really work.

The answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124630/heroku-flask-and-python-sockets) makes it sound like there is a way I can do it using http requests.

Is there a way to do that or am I running around in circles?